# yuidoc - reuse complex @param {Object}

Tags: javascript, documentation, yuidoc

I have a `Foo` object that gets passed around.

```
/**
 * Do something cool
 * 
 * @method baz
 * @param {Object} foo
 *     @param {String} foo.name
 *     @param {Number} foo.x
 *     @param {Number} foo.y
 *     @param {Number} foo.z
 */
Bar.prototype.baz = function (foo) { /* ... */ };
```

My foo object is a lot bigger and I don't want to have to repeat this for every single method that I document. I also don't want to have to go update a 100 methods every time `Foo`'s structure changes.

Is there a way to declare the `Foo` object structure separately (ala a type?) and then reference that from `@param` tags.

Comment: Did you try to do exactly that? A class with only properties?

Comment: @Prusse the problem is that I need nested properties.

Comment: relevant issue https://github.com/yui/yuidoc/issues/94